# CakePHP. Ajax request not working with debug = 0

Tags: php, security, cakephp

I am at a loss. I submit a form via Ajax using

```
submitForm: function(element) {
    $.post(
        webroot + 'users/settings',
        $('#AJAXform').serialize(),
        function() {
            var option = $('#AJAXform').find('select option:selected');
            $j.current.v.updateField(element, option.text());
            $j.current.v.removeForms();
        }
    );
}
```

Indeed everything works fine... that is, until I set the debug level to 0.

Then the Ajax request fails. But the strange thing is that via Firebug I can see that I get an error 404 with written

### Not Found

**Error:** 
    The requested address **'/users/profile'** was not found on this server.

The problem is that I'm NOT calling the page /users/profile but rather /users/settings (users/profile is the page on which the form is located). And this only happens with the debug level to 0. So I guess it's something related to security.

One may think I'm being blackholed, but the problem is that the Security component is not currently activated; moreover the blackhole should send a blank page, and not an error 404 (even less for the wrong page).

EDIT: I solved it. It turned out it was a redirect in the response which was giving an error. When debug = 0, that error would not be shown and a 404 would appear instead. Firefox would then guess the 404 message (which was not actually sent)

I solved it with

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Comment: If you're not going to delete the question now that you solved it yourself (so people with the same problem may find your solution), consider changing the title to something more descriptive.

Comment: or perhaps answer your won question so it is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It turned out it was a redirect in the response which was giving an error. When debug = 0, that error would not be shown and a 404 would appear instead. Firefox would then guess the 404 message (which was not actually sent)